# how to make a query using a parameter (http request) as a condition - Syntax error: Unexpected "<"

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a function in cloud-functions using python that queries a table in the big query.

The function receives a http request with an id per parameter. I'm trying to add a condition to my query from that parameter, but to no avail.

This is my code and the message I get when testing

```
#parameter {"id":"'2010101'"}

    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import requests

    def testefuction(data):

      client = bigquery.Client()
      query = "SELECT type,price FROM `product.products` WHERE id = " + str(data)
      query_job = client.query(query)  # API request
      rows = query_job.result()
      for row in rows:
        print("type={}, price ={}".format(row.type,row.price ))
```

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
400 Syntax error: Unexpected "<" at [1:79]



                                                                          -----Query Job SQL Follows-----                                                                          

    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |
   1:SELECT * FROM `product.products` WHERE id = <Request 'http://123123.com/' [POST]>
    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include details on where the data that gets passed to your function comes from.

Comment: Does the "data" parameter contain the information "<Request '123123.com' [POST]>"? If that's the case, you have to extract the id "123123" from the "data" variable and then just concatenate the id to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a Cloud Functions, the object that you have in [`flask.Request` object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request).
You can get the data from the POST body like this (Here you name the `flask.Request` object `data`)

```
# If JSON formatted body
request_json = data.get_json()
id = request_json['myJsonField']

# If body is text or custom 
body = data.get_data() 
# process body as you want
```

*NOTE: I don't know what is your use case, but your design smells the [SQL injection, one of the top OWASP security issue](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)*